# Best way to delete multiple keys with wildcard in redis-cli

Tags: bash, redis, node-redis, redis-cli

I want to run a bash script from node.js to remove all session keys from redis every time the server restarts. 
I have read somewhere that `Keys` shouldn't be used to delete multiple keys with a pattern because it would subject the server to security risks like DoS. Would this bash script a safer way to delete keys? Does `xargs -L 1000` mean in each loop it will delete 1000 keys? Am I understanding it correctly?

```
#!/bin/bash
redis-cli --scan --pattern "SESSION:*" | xargs -L 1000 redis-cli del
```

I took the comman line from [HERE](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-delete-multiple-keys-in-Redis).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have read somewhere that `Keys` shouldn't be used to delete multiple keys with a pattern because it would subject the server to security risks like DoS.

Not security, just denial of service while `KEYS` is running because it is blocking (and rarely an OOM scenario if the reply is too big).

> Would this bash script a safer way to delete keys?

I would say politer instead of safer - this one liner will allow other requests to be served between `SCAN`s instead of blocking the server for the duration.

> Does `xargs -L 1000` mean in each loop it will delete 1000 keys?

It means that every `DEL` will have up to 1000 keys, depending on the scan's results.

> I want to run a bash script from node.js to remove all session keys from redis every time the server restarts.

If your Redis instance is used solely for storing the sessions, you can consider `FLUSHALL`. Alternatively, if (and you should) every session key has a TTL, you can just use a per-server-restart prefix for your sessions and let older session expire naturally.